# Zend Studio PHP Short Tags

Tags: zend-studio

I am using Zend Studio 8.0 for Mac, every time I start to type the php tag it will autocomplete the full

```
<?php ?>
```

is there a way to set it to:

```
<?= ?>
```

I have looked at all the settings and I can't seem to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Window > Preferences, go to the PHP > Editor > Typing and un-check the "Add php after start tag" this will not solve your problem but will save you the action of removing the php token after you click '